# Como me proteger contra "MongoInjection"

Tags: mongodb, sql-injection, vulnerabilidade

Uso MongoDB em uma aplicação front-end que roda no Node.JS através da framework Express.

Gostaria de saber como criar proteções contra MongoDB "Injection" (similar a *sql injection*).

Comment: O termo correto seria NoSQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei o seguinte descritivo na thread do SOen e achei interessante compartilhar nessa sua questão:

O ponto é **converter e interpretar os dados de entrada**

*MongoDB evita potenciais problemas desse tipo por não realizar conversões de dados.
Ele não realiza conversões em estruturas de texto para descobrir o quê fazer, dessa forma não existe a possibilidade de má interpretação dos dados...*

Nessa referência possui um link indicativo sobre leitura complementar para ajudar em pontos ao escrever código seguro (caso seja uma preocupação).

Fonte: [How does MongoDB avoid the SQL injection mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021456/how-does-mongodb-avoid-the-sql-injection-mess)